# Having an issue with makeCopy function coming back as undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, error-handling

There isn't much code so I included it all.
I tried multiple things but I'm very new to this.

```
const Corefile = DriveApp.getFileById("19kvCzcOyi8_AG55NOidoumAo3pMQUHbjuKvaiQDyfaY"); 
  const Tempfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1G1BbJGTX2A9HE3q9x9GVFLwCzu-cbPE_");
  const Finishedfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1t7wuPWUfK5tSLVZ1luPrl7MGDlBJyMzf");


  function createNewestPDF(){        

  const Corefile = DriveApp.getFileById("19kvCzcOyi8_AG55NOidoumAo3pMQUHbjuKvaiQDyfaY");  
  const Tempfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1G1BbJGTX2A9HE3q9x9GVFLwCzu-cbPE_");
  const Finishedfolder = DriveApp.getFolderById("1t7wuPWUfK5tSLVZ1luPrl7MGDlBJyMzf");
  const Currentsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Dump(clean)");
  
  
  const Data = Currentsheet.getRange(Currentsheet.getLastRow(),1,Currentsheet.getLastRow(),116).getDisplayValues(); //Test to verify 116 is the total number of columns

 
  let errors = [];
   
  Data.forEach( row => {
  try{
  GenerateSheet(row[2],row[16],row[30],row[4],row[5],row[3],row[8],row[6],row[7],"BCBSM QA " + row[2] + " " + row[0],row[9],row[12],row[11],row[10],row[29],row[14],row[17],row[89],row[90],row[21],row[102],row[103],row[104],row[105],row[18],row[36],row[19],row[20],row[37],row[38],row[39],row[91],row[92],row[22],row[13],row[24],row[25],row[23],row[26],row[34],row[32],row[27],row[35],row[33],row[41],row[42],row[106],row[107],row[108],row[52],row[53],row[54],row[55],row[56],row[57],row[93],row[94],row[43],row[44],row[45],row[46],row[47],row[48],row[49],row[50],row[51],row[62],row[58],row[63],row[59],row[64],row[95],row[96],row[114],row[109],row[110],row[72],row[111],row[112],row[97],row[98],row[66],row[69],row[72],row[67],row[70],row[68],row[71],row[73],row[75],row[74],row[76],row[78],row[79],row[80],row[113],row[84],row[85],row[86],row[87],row[99],row[100],row[81],row[82],row[83],row[101],row[15],row[28],row[31],row[40],row[61],row[65],row[77],row[88],Corefile,Tempfolder,Finishedfolder);
  errors.push([""]); //(take the h off to create error and the system spits out failed AFTER row 17?????)
  }
  
  catch(err){

  errors.push(["failed"]);
  }  
          Currentsheet.getRange(Currentsheet.getLastRow(),117,Currentsheet.getLastRow(),1).setValue(errors);      
});
 

}  
 
 



function GenerateSheet(Agentname,TypeofReview,QLEselected,FirstcontactDate,Enrollmentdate,ClientsName,ClientsphoneNumber,AgentcubedCID,ConvosocallLogID,PdfName,Line1,Line2,Line3,Line4,Line5,Line6,
Line7,Line8,Line9,Line10,Line11,Line12,Line13,Line14,Line15,Line16,Line17,Line18,Line19,Line20,Line21,Line22,Line23,Line24,Line25,Line26,Line27,Line28,Line29,Line30,Line31,Line32,Line33,Line34,
Line35,Line36,Line37,Line38,Line39,Line40,Line41,Line42,Line43,Line44,Line45,Line46,Line47,Line48,Line49,Line50,Line51,Line52,Line53,Line54,Line55,Line56,Line57,Line58,Line59,Line60,Line61,Line62,
Line63,Line64,Line65,Line66,Line67,Line68,Line69,Line70,Line71,Line72,Line73,Line74,Line75,Line76,Line77,Line78,Line79,Line80,Line81,Line82,Line83,Line84,Line85,Line86,Line87,Line88,Line89,Line90,
Line91,Line92,Line93,Line94,Line95,Line96,Line97,Line98,Line99,Line100,Line101,Line102,Line103,Line104,Line105,Corefile,Tempfolder,Finishedfolder) { 


  
  
  
  
  const Tempcorefile = Corefile.makeCopy(Tempfolder); 
  const Tempcoredocfile = DocumentApp.openById(Tempcorefile.getId()); 
  const Body = Tempcoredocfile.getBody();
  Body.replaceText("{a1}", Agentname);
  Body.replaceText("{a2}", TypeofReview);
  Body.replaceText("{a3}", QLEselected);
  Body.replaceText("{a4}", FirstcontactDate);
  Body.replaceText("{a5}", Enrollmentdate);
  Body.replaceText("{a6}", ClientsName);
  Body.replaceText("{a7}", ClientsphoneNumber);
  Body.replaceText("{a8}", AgentcubedCID);
  Body.replaceText("{a9}", ConvosocallLogID);
  Body.replaceText("{b1}", Line1);
  Body.replaceText("{b2}", Line2);
  Body.replaceText("{b3}", Line3);
  Body.replaceText("{b4}", Line4);
  Body.replaceText("{b5}", Line5);
  Body.replaceText("{b6}", Line6);
  Body.replaceText("{b7}", Line7);
  Body.replaceText("{b8}", Line8);
  Body.replaceText("{b9}", Line9);
  Body.replaceText("{c1}", Line10);
  Body.replaceText("{c2}", Line11);
  Body.replaceText("{c3}", Line12);
  Body.replaceText("{c4}", Line13);
  Body.replaceText("{c5}", Line14);
  Body.replaceText("{c6}", Line15);
  Body.replaceText("{c7}", Line16);
  Body.replaceText("{c8}", Line17);
  Body.replaceText("{c9}", Line18);
  Body.replaceText("{c10}", Line19);
  Body.replaceText("{c11}", Line20);
  Body.replaceText("{c12}", Line21);
  Body.replaceText("{c13}", Line22);
  Body.replaceText("{c14}", Line23);
  Body.replaceText("{d1}", Line24);
  Body.replaceText("{d2}", Line25);
  Body.replaceText("{d3}", Line26);
  Body.replaceText("{d4}", Line27);
  Body.replaceText("{d5}", Line28);
  Body.replaceText("{d6}", Line29);
  Body.replaceText("{d7}", Line30);
  Body.replaceText("{d8}", Line31);
  Body.replaceText("{d9}", Line32);
  Body.replaceText("{d10}", Line33);
  Body.replaceText("{d11}", Line34); 
  Body.replaceText("{e1}", Line35);
  Body.replaceText("{e2}", Line36);
  Body.replaceText("{e3}", Line37);
  Body.replaceText("{e4}", Line38);
  Body.replaceText("{e5}", Line39);
  Body.replaceText("{e6}", Line40);
  Body.replaceText("{e7}", Line41);
  Body.replaceText("{e8}", Line42);
  Body.replaceText("{e9}", Line43);
  Body.replaceText("{e10}", Line44);
  Body.replaceText("{e11}", Line45);
  Body.replaceText("{e12}", Line46);
  Body.replaceText("{e13}", Line47);
  Body.replaceText("{f1}", Line48);
  Body.replaceText("{f2}", Line49);
  Body.replaceText("{f3}", Line50);
  Body.replaceText("{f4}", Line51);
  Body.replaceText("{f5}", Line52);
  Body.replaceText("{f6}", Line53);
  Body.replaceText("{f7}", Line54);
  Body.replaceText("{f8}", Line55);
  Body.replaceText("{f9}", Line56);
  Body.replaceText("{g1}", Line57);
  Body.replaceText("{g2}", Line58);
  Body.replaceText("{g3}", Line59);
  Body.replaceText("{g4}", Line60);
  Body.replaceText("{g5}", Line61);
  Body.replaceText("{g6}", Line62);
  Body.replaceText("{g7}", Line63);
  Body.replaceText("{h1}", Line64);
  Body.replaceText("{h2}", Line65);
  Body.replaceText("{h3}", Line66);
  Body.replaceText("{h4}", Line67);
  Body.replaceText("{h5}", Line68);
  Body.replaceText("{h6}", Line69);
  Body.replaceText("{h7}", Line70);
  Body.replaceText("{h8}", Line71);
  Body.replaceText("{h9}", Line72);
  Body.replaceText("{j1}", Line73);
  Body.replaceText("{j2}", Line74);
  Body.replaceText("{j3}", Line75);
  Body.replaceText("{j4}", Line76);
  Body.replaceText("{j5}", Line77);
  Body.replaceText("{j6}", Line78);
  Body.replaceText("{j7}", Line79);
  Body.replaceText("{k1}", Line80);
  Body.replaceText("{k2}", Line81);
  Body.replaceText("{k3}", Line82);
  Body.replaceText("{k4}", Line83); 
  Body.replaceText("{m1}", Line84);
  Body.replaceText("{m2}", Line85);
  Body.replaceText("{m3}", Line86);
  Body.replaceText("{m4}", Line87);
  Body.replaceText("{m5}", Line88);
  Body.replaceText("{m6}", Line89);
  Body.replaceText("{m7}", Line90);
  Body.replaceText("{m8}", Line91);
  Body.replaceText("{m9}", Line92);
  Body.replaceText("{m10}", Line93);
  Body.replaceText("{n1}", Line94);
  Body.replaceText("{n2}", Line95);
  Body.replaceText("{n3}", Line96);
  Body.replaceText("{z1}", Line97);
  Body.replaceText("{q1}", Line98);
  Body.replaceText("{q2}", Line99);
  Body.replaceText("{q3}", Line100);
  Body.replaceText("{q4}", Line101);
  Body.replaceText("{q5}", Line102);
  Body.replaceText("{q6}", Line103);
  Body.replaceText("{q7}", Line104);
  Body.replaceText("{q8}", Line105); 
  Tempcoredocfile.saveAndClose();

  const Blob = Tempcorefile.getAs(MimeType.PDF);
  Finishedfolder.createFile(Blob).setName(PdfName);

  Tempfolder.removeFile(Tempcorefile); 


}
```

The only thing I've found that might help is that the code seems to be encountering an error when it hits my "Data.forEach" line in the code so it jumps straight to my catch language. Any help is highly appreciated. This is meant to copy info dumped from a spreadsheet and translate it over to a premade doc file through the process laid out in the code above.

Comment: First comment: code is easier to debug when you properly indent your code. It is a I don't understand why you would want to make things more difficult with this zig zag mess.

Comment: `Currentsheet.getRange()` returns a Range object (`Data`). Range objects do not have a `forEach` method. You need the values from that range, so `Data.getValues().forEach`

Comment: How have you asserted that `makeCopy` returns undefined?

Comment: Your use of global Corefile and the CoreFile parameter in generate sheet seem to conflict.  Recommend changing one of their names.